# Music in Dunkview "Knack" review on YouTube (from the game soundtrack?)

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, pop

The song is in the background between 2:11 to 2:15. What song is it?

Answer (score 6):

That's [Junior Senior – Move Your Feet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_Your_Feet), originally released in 2002 in Denmark, and becoming a huge hit across the world the next year.